# Cannot load file or assembly nunit.framework when I create a new controller in MVC3

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, nunit

In this moment, I met a strange behaviour in VS2010. I cannot understand him.

Few days ago, I created many controllers in MVC3 application and many models.

Today, when I want to create a new **controller**, I received the following message:

[image: Visual studio error]

I mention that I have already installed a Nunit version (I think version 2.60)

What can I do in this case ?

Comment: to resolve this issue - i will remove Nunit reference compile and then again add correct Nunit reference to my project.

Comment: I have no reference to Nunit and never referenced this.

Comment: What other 3rd references you are using in MVC project?